# Check if value exist in array from JSON data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am pulling JSON data from etherscan and trying to see if an address exist in that transaction to see if it was sent or received.

what I want is to find all occurrences where the $pa is found in the from field and display them as "sent Transaction, hash = tx" and the same for the "to" field. So ultimately I will have a list of all the transactions and it will show if the transaction was sent or received.
My current code is:

```
$pa = '0xE460c28E4cE2e4aE0B934a3eeb8FD88134d26956'
$url = ("http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xE460c28E4cE2e4aE0B934a3eeb8FD88134d26956&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=MY API KEY");

$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
$data = $json['result'];

foreach ($data as $txinfo)
{
    $from =  array($txinfo['from'].',');
    $to = array($txinfo['to'].',');

    if (in_array($pa, $from))
    {
        echo 'found';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'not found';
    }
}
```

But it doesn't find the address even though it does exist in array.. Where am I going wrong? When the array is created all the keys are [0].

Here is the JSON data that is returned -

```
Array ( [0] => 0x87fdc1fd91cb8a7db0021f1d749027b7048874cb, ) Array ( [0] => 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956, ) Array ( [0] => 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956, ) Array ( [0] => 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956, ) Array ( [0] => 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956, )
```

Here is the raw JSON data when I print_r($data)

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [blockNumber] => 6625846
        [timeStamp] => 1541106828
        [hash] => 0xa35b44d7e2ff09f2c936d04ad53f472b3cae46b449ddd307b3bb0a9aa67aa7a0
        [nonce] => 18
        [blockHash] => 0x90cad8998ef5967f5a956d38a7cc37a5ffd00558d1d7e3bb93ae4fc9bae5d23e
        [transactionIndex] => 18
        [from] => 0x87fdc1fd91cb8a7db0021f1d749027b7048874cb
        [to] => 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956
        [value] => 56598736000000000
        [gas] => 21000
        [gasPrice] => 41000000000
        [isError] => 0 
        [txreceipt_status] => 1
        [input] => 0x
        [contractAddress] => 
        [cumulativeGasUsed] => 768594
        [gasUsed] => 21000
        [confirmations] => 5988
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [blockNumber] => 6631247
        [timeStamp] => 1541184437
        [hash] => 0x3f85168d763793e350b4273c531b055d37121b170a48675ba5decd80b62442d5
        [nonce] => 0
        [blockHash] => 0x9b6ff77963fd564d5c2beee5ce0117a0be23e9f30bb9561d931faa6fb4c1efa9
        [transactionIndex] => 8
        [from] => 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956
        [to] => 0x1faae436c85a15f257f7ff7f02af1e608815bbd7
        [value] => 0
        [gas] => 900000
        [gasPrice] => 40000000000
        [isError] => 0
        [txreceipt_status] => 1
        [input] => 0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000129a92832d78cda2a89e9ea09cd688e4b692a93c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b5e3af16b1880000
        [contractAddress] => 
        [cumulativeGasUsed] => 1221338
        [gasUsed] => 52200 
        [confirmations] => 587
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [blockNumber] => 6631287
        [timeStamp] => 1541184985
        [hash] => 0x621de75f0a2a880e17efc2c40a310223c38fa19b71b2dae375a9bc4d4d794a1a
        [nonce] => 1
        [blockHash] => 0x9c9433a4e22b107b0a9e84e2db5d4878d89e1f03730fd4cf3b7095f253418da8
        [transactionIndex] => 1
        [from] => 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956
        [to] => 0x1faae436c85a15f257f7ff7f02af1e608815bbd7
        [value] => 0
        [gas] => 900000
        [gasPrice] => 40000000000
        [isError] => 0
        [txreceipt_status] => 1
        [input] => 0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000008336093a98fedc5df4e055a86c87fb79a68f64950000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015af1d78b58c40000
        [contractAddress] =>
        [cumulativeGasUsed] => 73200
        [gasUsed] => 52200
        [confirmations] => 547
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [blockNumber] => 6631362
        [timeStamp] => 1541186019
        [hash] => 0x4a32e142b627a1541d0dc5605ef9c52b7f586f02ab502d13d0503321622ba435
        [nonce] => 2
        [blockHash] => 0x52d376055a2f73f20a2e3f0b7872403ee1d6a35c8903549116a975bd0c3d865f
        [transactionIndex] => 14
        [from] => 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956
        [to] => 0x1faae436c85a15f257f7ff7f02af1e608815bbd7
        [value] => 0
        [gas] => 900000
        [gasPrice] => 40000000000
        [isError] => 0
        [txreceipt_status] => 1
        [input] => 0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000008336093a98fedc5df4e055a86c87fb79a68f64950000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000
        [contractAddress] =>
        [cumulativeGasUsed] => 380279
        [gasUsed] => 37136
        [confirmations] => 472
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [blockNumber] => 6631368
        [timeStamp] => 1541186117
        [hash] => 0x0b40f67a334aae4cd54977e5e4cd5f54a2157f75441d5143d1eed4ba70f19b8f
        [nonce] => 3
        [blockHash] => 0x68981c00f3a7cff76938a852d9f4e96888ecee81ab51632764c86ce6b1ded910
        [transactionIndex] => 48
        [from] => 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956
        [to] => 0x1faae436c85a15f257f7ff7f02af1e608815bbd7
        [value] => 0 
        [gas] => 900000
        [gasPrice] => 40000000000
        [isError] => 0
        [txreceipt_status] => 1
        [input] => 0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000008336093a98fedc5df4e055a86c87fb79a68f64950000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000
        [contractAddress] =>
        [cumulativeGasUsed] => 1661953
        [gasUsed] => 37136
        [confirmations] => 466
    )
)
```

Comment: That loop you have made will echo a "found" or "not found" on every `$txtinfo` element you are looping. For a good implement, you should define a `$found=false` before entering the loop, then in the loop check this condition: `if (in_array($pa, $from)) {$found=true; break;}`. Now, at the end of the array add `echo $found`. But there can be others issues, you should add a sample of the JSON received if you want to found an accurate answer.

Comment: Ok thanks I will update the question, I am just doing found/not found until I can get the function working..

Comment: You are sure the JSON you have pushed is like that, because i don't see the **tags**: `result`, `from` and `to` that you are trying to access on it...

Comment: yes, I will change it to the raw json data. That is returning just the "From"

Comment: Why do you use the `array()` function? It seems to serve no purpose... I mean, why not just compare `$pa` with `$txtinfo['from']` directly?

Comment: Because it gives me all the address strung together without breaks. Iit makes one long string so 0x123 wouldnt equal 0x1230x1230x123.. etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cut down your sample data to only contain the necessary parts.  `in_array()` doesn't seem like the right tool for this job.  Also, you will need case-insensitive matching OR you can more simply call `strtolower()` on `$pa`.  By storing the respective matches in dedicated subarrays, you can simply output the data to the screen when the loop is finished.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/P2GhE))

```
$data = [
    ['hash' => '0xa35b44d7e2ff09f2c936d04ad53f472b3cae46b449ddd307b3bb0a9aa67aa7a0',
     'from' => '0x87fdc1fd91cb8a7db0021f1d749027b7048874cb',
     'to' => '0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956'],
    ['hash' =>'0x3f85168d763793e350b4273c531b055d37121b170a48675ba5decd80b62442d5',
     'from' => '0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956',
     'to' => '0x1faae436c85a15f257f7ff7f02af1e608815bbd7'],
    ['hash' => '0x621de75f0a2a880e17efc2c40a310223c38fa19b71b2dae375a9bc4d4d794a1a',
     'from' => '0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956',
     'to' => '0x1faae436c85a15f257f7ff7f02af1e608815bbd7'],
    ['hash' => '0x4a32e142b627a1541d0dc5605ef9c52b7f586f02ab502d13d0503321622ba435',
     'from' => '0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956',
     'to' => '0x1faae436c85a15f257f7ff7f02af1e608815bbd7'],
    ['hash' => '0x0b40f67a334aae4cd54977e5e4cd5f54a2157f75441d5143d1eed4ba70f19b8f',
     'from' => '0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956',
     'to' => '0x1faae436c85a15f257f7ff7f02af1e608815bbd7']
];
$pa = strtolower('0xE460c28E4cE2e4aE0B934a3eeb8FD88134d26956');

$result = ['from' => [], 'to' => []];
foreach ($data as $set) {
    if ($pa == $set['from']) {
        $result['Sent'][] = $set['hash'];
    } elseif ($pa == $set['to']) {
        $result['Received'][] = $set['hash'];
    }
}

echo "For $pa\n";
echo "Sent Transactions:\n\t" , implode("\n\t", $result['Sent']) , "\n";
echo "Received Transactions:\n\t" , implode("\n\t", $result['Received']);
```

Output:

```
For 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956
Sent Transactions:
    0x3f85168d763793e350b4273c531b055d37121b170a48675ba5decd80b62442d5
    0x621de75f0a2a880e17efc2c40a310223c38fa19b71b2dae375a9bc4d4d794a1a
    0x4a32e142b627a1541d0dc5605ef9c52b7f586f02ab502d13d0503321622ba435
    0x0b40f67a334aae4cd54977e5e4cd5f54a2157f75441d5143d1eed4ba70f19b8f
Received Transactions:
    0xa35b44d7e2ff09f2c936d04ad53f472b3cae46b449ddd307b3bb0a9aa67aa7a0
```

Comment: Holy cow thank you so much! you put a ton of effort into helping me and I truly appreciate it! It works just like I wanted cheers mate!!

Comment: It is my pleasure.

Comment: Is there a simple way to combine the list back in its regular succession so its order by date received/sent? Or should I ask that as a new question. Ive tried what I can think of but Im not sure the correct method to do this. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't mind making minor adjustments.  What is your exact desired output? It may be easiest to send me your thoughts in a 3v4l.org link.

Comment: Wow thats so kind of you! Basically im looking for the list to be combined in its natural order rather than separated by "sent" and "received" I will try and get that link for you

Answer (score 0):

You append a «,» to $from. That’s why your in_array() return false

EDIT:

$pa = '0xE460c28E4cE2e4aE0B934a3eeb8FD88134d26956'

[from] => 0xe460c28e4ce2e4ae0b934a3eeb8fd88134d26956

In_array():

Note:
If needle is a string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive manner.

Comment: Im not sure im understanding what you are telling me

Comment: Try this: $from = array($txtinfo[‘from’]);

Comment: Please do a var_dump() on both $pa and $txtinfo[‘from’] inside the foreach-loop